# AEM: How to pass/check Sightly variable in a javascript function call?

Tags: aem, sightly

I have the following function javascript function call.

```
<script>myFunctionHere({log:true})</script>
```

I want to check the value of property (checkbox dialog) so I can pass the required value but it's not working.

I tried:

```
<script>myFunctionHere({log:${properties.logme ? 'true' : 'false'}})</script>
```

But when I looked at the resulting HTML, it looks like this:

```
<script>myFunctionHere({log:})</script>
```

Any ideas how it can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [specification of HTL language](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#113-context-sensitive), you need to set an explicit context for expressions inside the `script` tag:

> For style and script contexts, it is mandatory to set a context. If the context isn't set, the expression shouldn't output anything

In your case, you would probably write something like:

```
<script>myFunctionHere({log:${properties.logme ? 'true' : 'false' @ context='scriptToken'}})</script>
```